# AWS S3 using JavaScript SDK: listObjects for unauthenticated, public users

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[AWS JavaScript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS.html) has methods for [listing all objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property) in an S3 bucket, but you have to use this method as an authenticated IAM.

Is there a way to create an IAM that can be assumed by any public user and then use that IAM to list the contents of the bucket?

Or is there any other way to list the contents of the bucket publicly using the front-end JavaScript SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to do this would be to use [Amazon Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/details/#guest), which allows 'guest' access to the APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind of old but I just found this: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/commit/7a8e257f32d984821a8661422070fb861659015f

It's a method for the **AWS.S3()** javascript sdk object, so one can make unathenticated requests to the api. Works great with public buckets.

Comment: How would i go about ensuring that call is made? Do I still need to enter credentials when entering the config details? ie `aws.config.update()`